# Facebook Open Graph scraping base URL instead of actual URL

Tags: facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

My portfolio page has separate Meta tags for each subpage, but I am struggling - facebook is only scraping my main page https://larsejaas.com
As of now, anyone sharing my page will get the same meta image and title+description for any page.
The page is build in Gatsby and hosted with Netlify

I have used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to debug the issue but nothing seems to work. On Twitter all subpages are recognized correctly.

If I scrape https://larsejaas.com/grafik I get the following redirect path in the facebook sharing debugger:

```
Redirect Path   
Input URL   arrow-right https://larsejaas.com/grafik
301 HTTP Redirect   arrow-right https://larsejaas.com/grafik/
og:url Meta Tag arrow-right https://larsejaas.com/
```

Can anybody help me pin-point the issue here?

This is a snippet of the meta headers from https://larsejaas.com/grafik:

```
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://larsejaas.com/grafik/" hreflang="x-default" data-react-helmet="true">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://larsejaas.com/grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://larsejaas.com/en/grafik/" hreflang="en" data-react-helmet="true">    
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://larsejaas.com/grafik/" hreflang="da" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://larsejaas.com/grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="description" content=" Besøg mit portfolio af grafiske illustrationer og animationer som jeg har lavet til brug i web projekter. Vektorgrafik, webanimationer og 3D grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Lars Ejaas | Grafisk arbejde med illustrationer og webanimationer" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content=" Besøg mit portfolio af grafiske illustrationer og animationer som jeg har lavet til brug i web projekter. Vektorgrafik, webanimationer og 3D grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://larsejaas.com/SoMe/open_graph_phone.png" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="twitter:data1" content="1 min." data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Lars Ejaas | Grafisk arbejde med illustrationer og webanimationer" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://larsejaas.com/SoMe/open_graph_phone.png" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://larsejaas.com/SoMe/open_graph_phone.png" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta property="og:description" content=" Besøg mit portfolio af grafiske illustrationer og animationer som jeg har lavet til brug i web projekter. Vektorgrafik, webanimationer og 3D grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Lars Ejaas | Grafisk arbejde med illustrationer og webanimationer" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta itemprop="description" content=" Besøg mit portfolio af grafiske illustrationer og animationer som jeg har lavet til brug i web projekter. Vektorgrafik, webanimationer og 3D grafik" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://larsejaas.com/SoMe/open_graph_phone.png" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="article:published_time" content="2021-02-26T16:46:53.619Z" data-react-helmet="true">
    <meta name="article:modified_time" content="2021-02-26T16:46:53.619Z" data-react-helmet="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

If anyone stumble upon the same issue on Netlify, you need to enable prerendering under build and deploy settings for the page. This will make all pages discoverable by Facebook.